# How to make Multiple Navigation in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I want to setup navigations as I have shown in the image. The app must contain a `drawer-navigation`, `bottom-tab-navigation`, `cart-screen` as a `full-screen modal` which should be open from tab's screens and `map-screen` as a `full-screen` modal which should be open from tab's screen C. The drawer must be open by clicking a button inside the tab screens.
Here is the diagram to demonstrate the requirement of app navigations

[image]

Comment: React Navigation's example folder is a good start. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/example

Comment: Here is the snack link of your project https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation:example but I am getting errors while running your project.  I hope you will look forward to it. Thanks for your support.